# Bootstrap panel as a container and using different style on cellphone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 40%; text-align: center; align-content: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <div class="panel-heading">User Information</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>The following table contains some personal information about users.</p>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want that the table will always be inside the panel no matter the size of the table, Another thing is if the user uses phone the width of the panel will be 100%.
how to achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for the width problem

Answer (score 1):

The `.table-responsive` class is only designed to be responsive on mobile devices...

But you  can add the class into your css without the media query and get the functionality at any viewport.

But note that this does not shrink the table, it only gives a horizontal scroll bar...

Below is the `.table-responsive` classes from Bootstrap without the media query restricting it to 768px and below.

```
.table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.table-responsive>.table { 
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table-responsive>.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table-responsive>.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table-responsive>.table>tfoot>tr>td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually I want to expand the panel and not shrink the table

Comment: I added this code to bootstrap.css and it didn't change anything when accessing the page via phone.